# Calculate the percentile rank of a value in a multiple dimensional data array

Tags: numpy, scipy, python-xarray

In xarray, I have the following 3-dimensional DataArray `vwc` with `time`, `latitude` and `longitude`.

```
<xarray.DataArray 'VWC' (time: 16436, latitude: 106, longitude: 193)>
array([[[ 4.537527,  4.586913, ...,  5.120861,  5.542567],
        [ 4.741828,  4.741827, ...,  4.930689,  5.693698],
        ...,
        [ 9.545872,  8.681304, ...,  4.581591,  5.490883],
        [10.35586 ,  9.848556, ...,  4.95035 ,  5.419432]],

       [[ 9.337118,  9.496598, ..., 16.893394, 16.874586],
        [ 9.223562,  9.411149, ..., 16.672445, 17.068016],
        ...,
        [ 7.645049,  7.807   , ...,  6.727722,  9.154998],
        [ 8.22339 ,  8.513931, ...,  5.427549,  7.602291]],

       ...,

       [[ 5.752615,  5.445625, ...,  4.107596,  4.543602],
        [ 6.709205,  6.498062, ...,  4.02037 ,  4.55328 ],
        ...,
        [16.67159 , 18.651648, ...,  7.272799,  6.543073],
        [14.757328, 14.930978, ...,  7.646502,  6.919951]],

       [[ 5.468747,  5.749045, ...,  2.450518,  2.36287 ],
        [ 5.763913,  5.773948, ...,  2.760434,  2.681414],
        ...,
        [12.102039, 12.021021, ...,  4.633275,  5.042778],
        [ 9.283951, 13.921013, ...,  4.446116,  4.824095]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1972-12-01 1972-12-02 ... 2017-11-30
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -39.2 -39.149525 ... -33.950478 -33.9
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 140.8 140.84792 140.89584 ... 149.95209 150.0
```

I need to calculate the percentile rank of `VWC` = 22 for each grid point (latitude, longitude) for each season, namely SON (Sep, Oct, Nov), DJF (Dec, Jan, Feb), MAM (Mar, Apr, May), JJA (Jun, Jul, Aug).

I checked the scipy.stats.percentileofscore function but this one does not seem to work for a multiple array along the `time` dimension.

Comment: Gonna need a bit more of a [mcve] for this.  What exactly is the input and expected output?

Comment: The input are a 3-dimensional array named vwc (data type of float) and a float value of "22.0". I need to check the percentile rank of "22.0" along the "time" dimension.